# Angular's ng-cookies Can Delete Client-Set Cookies But Not Server-Set (from MVC) Cookies (IE Only)

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, cookies

Works fine in other browsers.

I think that what is happening is that MVC is setting the cookie with path="/" and the Angular code is running from the context of a specific application page (for example, "/posts").

Can Angular ng-cookies delete a cookie that is stored at a higher level than the URL of the page it is running on?  (Note again that this works fine in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there is no such thing as a "server cookie" or "client cookie".  Cookies are cookies.

Maybe check your IE settings to ensure it's not preventing the use of cookies?